# PHP - Array within array extraction

Tags: php, parsing, multidimensional-array

My brain isn't grasping the multi-dimensional array extraction too well this evening.

This is the result of my code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (<b>John Smith</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2012-02-07 00:00:20 GMT</b><hr>This is a comment posted<br><br>
            [1] => (<b>Alex Boom</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2013-02-07 00:08:06 GMT</b><hr>And let's put some more in here<br />with a new line.
        )

)
```

I need to just loop through the internal array, so I can manipulate the text.

Here's my code that's actually producing what you see:

```
<?php
$notecomments = '(<b>John Smith</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2012-02-07 00:00:20 GMT</b><hr>This is a comment posted<br><br>(<b>Alex Boom</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2013-02-07 00:08:06 GMT</b><hr>And let's put some more in here<br />with a new line.';

if(preg_match_all('/\(<b>(?:(?!\(<b>).)*/s', $notecomments, $matches)){
print_r($matches);
}

?>
```

I've tried `foreach($matches as $key => $val)` , and it produces this: `Array`

I'm sure it's not a difficult thing to get into this, but I'm drawing a serious blank.
Help

Comment: You'll need another level of depth. Either `foreach($matches[0] as $key => $val)` or `foreach ($matches as $array) { foreach ($array as $key => $val) {} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting one level deeper:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
$prod = [];
$keys = array_keys($arraydata); // get keys of the main array
for($i = 0; $i < count($arraydata); $i++) { // loop through the main array
    foreach($arraydata[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) { //loop through the keys collected
            $prod[] = $value; // return array
    }
}
```